# Date regular expression does not work

Tags: javascript

The text box does not accept any key values on running the code. If I just use /\d/ it works and accepts only digits. How can I make this work for dates too?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('Form submitted!')" id="myForm">
    <div>
        <label>Type a phone number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="birthday" name="yourBirthday" value="">
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday");

        birthday.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
            var characterEntered = event.charCode;
            if (!/\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}/.test(String.fromCharCode(characterEntered))) {
                event.preventDefault()
            }


        }, false)

    })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `event.charCode;` is one char. I suppose that you want to block chars like digit or hypen. So the proper regular expression is `\d|[-]` which means digit or hypen

Check JSFiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m629pL3n/

Comment: @user3837378 just mark my response as answer, you don't need to thanks on SO

Comment: Is there a better way to do it, without using charCode? 

PS : One more minute left to mark your response as answer.

Comment: The problem which I can see is that user can enter string like 2222222222-222-222-2222-121222-2222-2222 and your validation will won't work